# Multitouch detects 2 taps only

Tags: c++, screen, cocos2d-x, multi-touch, cocos2d-x-3.0

in CppTest Multitouch demo, when I tap the screen with 3 fingers, only 2 cross-lines are drawn at once instead of 3.

Is that 2 tap limitation due to my mobile hardware? or

Is there a way to detect more than 2 taps at once?

I use cocos2d-x v3.3 final on an Archos Titanium 40 (os 4.2.2).

I've created a test project based on EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce and that's the same. Only 2 fingers are detected at once only.

```
void    TLayer::onEnter() 
{
    auto L = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();

    L->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(TLayer::OnTouchesBegan, this);
    L->onTouchesMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(TLayer::OnTouchesMoved, this);
    L->onTouchesEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(TLayer::OnTouchesEnded, this);    
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(L, this);
}
void    TLayer::OnTouchesBegan (const vector<Touch *> &touches, Event *event) 
{
    static int      TapCount=0;
    TapCount+;

    CCLOG("onTouchesBegan: TAP: %d", TapCount);
}
void    TLayer::OnTouchesMoved (const vector<Touch *> &touches, Event *event) 
{ 
}
void    TLayer::OnTouchesEnded(const vector<Touch *> &touches, Event *event) 
{
    CCLOG("OnTouchesEnded...");
}
```

when I launch this sample then tap 3 fingers, logs are only showing for 2 fingers not 3 :

```
onTouchesBegan: TAP: 1
onTouchesBegan: TAP: 2
OnTouchesEnded...
OnTouchesEnded...
```

missing is **TAP: 3**  . As I said , I get the same behaviour when running the CppTest / Multitouch demo from v3.3 final.

Comment: post your code, we don't  give guesses as answers

Comment: Please answer at least for the CPPtest part, which is common sample code.  CPPtest/Multitouch sample in v3.3 allows 2 fingers touch at max, when I run it on my android phone , why? That's a part of my question.

Comment: Quick google brought up that at least a related model (Archos 70) has only a 2-touch touchscreen: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archos#Generation_8

Comment: http://www.phonemore.com/phone/archos-40-titanium/1383 saying that it's a 5 multipoint hardware. ??? Thanks for knowing that some hardware are limited to 2 taps as for the 70 series.

Comment: Maybe it is, maybe the specs are wrong. Wouldn't be the first time to see incorrect specs on reseller websites. Try verify this with device vendor, they should have accurate specs.

Comment: I don't think it's a cocos2d-x limit either. Otherwise that would be a frequently debated issue. It may be possible that the device needs to be "switched" to 5-point mode multitouch. Ie on iOS the touch handling defaults to single-toch unless you expressly enable multitouch. Could be an energy-saving feature by the OS framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think now that I'm limited by my hardware. My 2-taps limitation is not due to cocos2dx restriction.

I have a project which needs to handle 3 taps at once, so I'll need to detect the hardware capacity first before deciding to adapt the application to 2 taps or not.

So if you have a multitouch project as me, consider that hardware can restrict you, before going deeper in your development.  thanks